# How to write multiple statements in Ternary operator?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, operators, ternary-operator

I am posting this question because I found nothing similar regarding this type of post.
**I am learning ternary operators.**
I want to perform action like shown below:

```
  bool Divisible = false;
  foreach (var Number in NumberList))
  {
    var  Number = 242;
    if ((Number %= 2) | (Number %= 6))
    {
       Divisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
       Divisible = false;
    }
  }
```

We can write this using the ternary operator like this:

```
var Divisible = (Number %= 2 | Number %= 6) ? false : true ;
```

But **if in else block there are multiple statements then what to do?**

```
  bool Divisible = false;
  foreach (var Number in NumberList))
  {
    var  Number = 242;
    if ((Number %= 2) | (Number %= 6))
    {
       Divisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
       Divisible = false;
       break;
    }
  }
```

How can we write ternary operator with multiple else statements?
Please share your knowledge of ternary operators.

Comment: "like this:" Like what? Something seems to be missing from your question.

Comment: Why would you want to use ternary operators for things there weren't designed for and obfuscate your code? Keep it readable by using if-else statements, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Everything has it's own merit. In your case, you have no option than using `if .. else` construct.

Comment: Hey BoltClock, Thanks for telling me that i missed to write ternary statement. Now question is complete. Please guide if you can. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This code won't compile since you're reassigning the loop variable inside the loop. Also, what's up with the usage of assignment operator?

Answer (score 5):

> But if in else block there are multiple statements then what to do?

If the statements are unrelated, then you don't use the conditional operator. Just use an if-else like you already have.

In your case, since your code needs to break if and only if `Divisible` is set to false, then you **cannot** use a conditional operator even if you wanted to hack it in, because a break is a statement, not an expression, and therefore cannot appear as part of a conditional operator.

In general, you only use the conditional operator when you want to decide between assigning one of two *values* based on a condition. For *anything* else, you should really be using a regular if-else construct. Don't try to shoehorn the conditional operator into just about any decision-making code because you'll more often than not find yourself running into problems such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator (that "shorthand if-else") is only intended to evaluate one of two statements based on the boolean. It's not so much a flow-control construct like if; it actually returns the result of the statement it executes. You can't use it to execute code like that.

You can read more on how the ternary operator works here [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx)

Also for your original code you can just do the following :

```
var Divisible = !(Number %= 2 | Number %= 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a arguably a shockingly bad idea but you could call methods in the ternary operators that return the type the assignment is looking for. eg

```
string doNotDoThis = yeahNah ? iToldYou(bad) : notToDoThis(idea);

// ...

string iToldYou(object thing)
    {
    // you can do stuff here with thing but seriously?
    return "yeahNah was yeah";
    }

string notToDoThis(object thing)
    {
    // you can do stuff here with thing but seriously?
    return "yeahNah was nah";
    }
```